# How to get the "Peer Pressure" badge

Tags: discussion, badges

What reasonable ways are there to get the *[Peer Pressure](https://superuser.com/badges/36/peer-pressure)* badge on SU?

> Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower.

---

I'm serious here: I don't particularly want to provide false information, write off-topic or unhelpful (ranting?) answers or ask really poor questions (such as the [most recent](https://superuser.com/questions/371048/connecting-a-macbook-to-an-old-television) recipient of this badge). I consider that badge more difficult to get (on purpose) than [this gold badge](https://superuser.com/badges/42/fanatic), which is also owned by a larger number of users than the bronze badge on this site.

**Bad answers** will more freely be commented on, edited, or flagged (and then usually be deleted), as it costs reputation to down vote.

**Bad questions** will be more freely down voted (which is good), but hardly ever do they get enough down votes before they collected the close votes and/or flags that will stop the down voting.

We just don't have a user community as large as SO (where there were twice as many *Peer Pressure* badges awarded than *Fanatic* badges) that allows us to easily get this badge.

Comment: I always thought it was a stupid badge. It encourages nothing. I would just take a bikeshed question and provide a wrong answer that still sounds like a real one. Or get people in chat to downvote a dummy post.

Comment: @slhck The former is possibly destructive and will get flagged and deleted too quickly (down votes don't accumulate by themselves, it takes people to read them, and they will flag), and the latter is cheating. We just have too many good moderators, both "community" and diamonds.

Comment: Also, ***yes*** it's a stupid badge. But: *"Bronze badges are awarded for basic use of Super User. They are easy to earn."* This is just not true for this badge. Basic use (participating for a while and using every feature once) *does not* award this badge.

Comment: [Example](http://superuser.com/a/371958/48078) of a post that will probably reach -3 soon and would be deleted by the OP.

Comment: @slhck It looks like that question ended up being sufficiently worthwhile that some thought it worth upvotes...

Comment: @killermist slhck is linking to a (now deleted) answer. It's still -3 score.

Comment: What's funny is the badge still exists on stackoverflow but is almost impossible to get because -3 answer -> autodelete. (I got one before it was implemented for a shockingly bad answer.) I'm kind of disappointed about the loss of rep from a controversial answer that got ended up downvoted really far but yet netted me lots of rep until the autodelete script was implemented and whacked it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [similar post over on Stackoverflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255671/2671341). Their idea is that badges are supposed to encourage good behavior on the site, and deleting one's own down-voted question or answer is good behavior—keeps the site tidy.